# Package install failed - creating new Angular app using CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am creating a new Angular app using CLI, got the error as shown below.

**Command run**

```
C:\Angular>ng new hello-world
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
```

**Error**

```
npm ERR! code ENOENT
npm ERR! syscall rename
npm ERR! path C:\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\regexp.prototype.flags\node_modules\es-abstract
npm ERR! dest C:\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\regexp.prototype.flags\node_modules\.es-abstract.DELETE
npm ERR! errno -4058
npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename 'C:\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\regexp.prototype.flags\node_modules\es-abstract' -> 'C:\Angular\hello-world\node_modules\regexp.prototype.flags\node_modules\.es-abstract.DELETE'
npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
npm ERR! enoent

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\e5544251\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-09-12T14_13_39_206Z-debug.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
```

**Agular CLI version**

```
C:\Users\e5544251>ng v

     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/


Angular CLI: 9.1.7
Node: 12.14.0
OS: win32 x64

Angular:
...
Ivy Workspace:

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.901.7
@angular-devkit/core         9.1.7
@angular-devkit/schematics   9.1.7
@schematics/angular          9.1.7
@schematics/update           0.901.7
rxjs                         6.5.4


C:\Users\e5544251>
```

**NPM version**

```
C:\Users\e5544251>npm -v
6.13.4
```

Comment: is your npm version latest?

Comment: @ Sandrin Joy `npm version` - `6.13.4`

Comment: in a situation like this I often clean the npm cache. Can you try `npm cache clean` or `npm cache verify`?

Comment: are you creating an angular app inside a nodejs project?

Comment: @Sandrin Joy, I am not sure about your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have deleted the existing folder and try the same command again it got succeded.

`C:\Angular>ng new hello-world`

```
C:\Angular>ng new hello-world
? Would you like to add Angular routing? No
? Which stylesheet format would you like to use? CSS
CREATE hello-world/angular.json (3606 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/package.json (1244 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/README.md (1027 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/tsconfig.json (489 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/tslint.json (3125 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/.editorconfig (274 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/.gitignore (631 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/browserslist (429 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/karma.conf.js (1023 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/tsconfig.app.json (210 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/tsconfig.spec.json (270 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/favicon.ico (948 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/index.html (296 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/main.ts (372 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/polyfills.ts (2835 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/styles.css (80 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/test.ts (753 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/assets/.gitkeep (0 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/environments/environment.prod.ts (51 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/environments/environment.ts (662 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.module.ts (314 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.html (25725 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.spec.ts (957 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.ts (215 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/src/app/app.component.css (0 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/protractor.conf.js (808 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/tsconfig.json (214 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/src/app.e2e-spec.ts (644 bytes)
CREATE hello-world/e2e/src/app.po.ts (301 bytes)
√ Packages installed successfully.
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up doing this to fix this error. This is my first time posting on here, I hope it helps :)

```
    npm cache clean --force
    sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/myname/.npm"
    npm install -g @angular/cli
```

Output

```
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall rmdir
npm ERR! path /Users/myname/.npm/_cacache/content-v2/sha512/17/e8
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Your cache folder contains root-owned files, due to a bug in
npm ERR! previous versions of npm which has since been addressed.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! To permanently fix this problem, please run:
npm ERR!   sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/myname/.npm"

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/myname/.npm/_logs/2023-04-10T08_27_38_382Z-debug-0.log
myname-mbp Code % sudo chown -R 501:20 "/Users/myname-mbp/.npm"
Password:
myname-mbp Code % npm cache clean --force
npm WARN using --force Recommended protections disabled.
myname-mbp Code % npm install -g @angular/cli
npm WARN deprecated @npmcli/move-file@2.0.1: This functionality has been moved to @npmcli/fs

added 239 packages in 11s
```